# The union of two open sets is open visualization.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Theorem 3.2.3 of Abott's Real Analysis textbook states that the union of an arbitrary collection of open sets is open. I am just wondering if I am visualizing this correctly. Say we take the open set (1,2) and the open set (3,4). Then the union would be (1,2,3,4). Would the new open set then be (1,4) such that all $\forall x, 1 < x < 4$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The open set $(1,2)$ is an interval containing all numbers between $1$ and $2$ (but not including $1$ or $2$). Similarly for $(3,4)$. The union of two sets is the set of numbers which are in *either* set. In this case, the union of $(1,2)$ and $(3,4)$ is no longer an interval.

You can picture $(1,2)\cup(3,4)$ by taking the real number line and sort of painting a unit-length strip between $1$ and $2$ and another between $3$ and $4$. Maybe the paint sort of fades out right at the edges to denote the endpoints are not included. But the area between $2$ and $3$ is *not* included. You might picture all of $(-\infty,1]$, $[2,3]$, and $[4,\infty)$ as white space.

Comment: Thank you very much that really helps my visual understanding of it <3

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. When we write $(1,2)$ and $(3,4)$, we mean they're intervals on the real line. So their union would just be $(1,2)\cup(3,4)$. To get the union you wrote, one writes $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$, which are each (closed in the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ (why?)) sets containing $2$ elements, whose union is $\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Comment: Thank you man :)